# How to make moving detected hand and fingertips interact with Qt GUI like a mouse?

Tags: c++, qt, augmented-reality

I'm making this fingertip-driven app ( OpenCV 2.3.2 + Qt 4.7 being developed in Visual Studio 2010 ) in which I'd like to utilize Qt's GUI especially its dialogs. The fingertip's position will be detected and tracked through VideoCapture. Imagine Microsoft Windows' Paint being used with one fingertip. I've been speculating about the following options:

- subclassing QEvent and installing an eventFilter to the widget to filter out unnecessary events
- subclassing QCursor if mouse events are dependent on cursor positions
- making my own color picker and other input dialogs which doesn't subclass any of Qt's specialized dialogs, which is what I'd probably end up doing if none of the above are feasible. I looked into QColorDialog's source code and found QColorWell and QColorLuminancePicker and am now thinking of the least tedious way to similar widgets.

What could be the most practical and the least computationally intensive way to do this? Sorry if my English wasn't clear or confusing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though your intention is to use opencv, your question has nothing to do with opencv, technically speaking. I suggest removing the tag.

Comment: Tag removed. Please point out any other edits that you suggest. This is my first question here in SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate this behavior by implementing [QTouchEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtouchevent.html) and calling that event simultaneously by your possible image processing thread. You just need to generate parameters needed by QTouchEvent (touch points, locations etc) by your image processing algorithm.

Comment: Can't wait to try that out! Thanks!

Comment: I'm now working on your suggestion. I hope somebody upvotes your answer because I can't right now. I have the rep of an SO noob = 11!